# QUdpSocket : I'm receiving a struct, how do I use it?

Tags: c++, networking, struct, qudpsocket

via a QUdpSocket, I know I'll receive datas which will contain only this struct:

```
typedef struct myStruct
    {
       int nb_trame;
       std::vector<bool> vBool;
    } myStruct;
```

but when I receive new datas, I receive a QByteArray right ?
So how can I use the received-struct ?

Comment: It depends how this structure was serialized, before was sended to you.

Comment: @tty6 just sending like that : 
    `MyStruct data;
    viaUdp->write( (const char*) &data, sizeof (data));`

Answer (score 0):

You can't entity-serialize a vector (your way of sending the struct is called entity-serialization). I mean, you can serialize it, but if you attempt to deserialize it this way you will not get a valid object.

You need to implement proper serialization.

Comment: So if I use a `bool myTab[20]` instead of my vector, It will be fine ?

Comment: @BastienNicolau, entity-serialization is frown upon, and rightfuly so. It is OK in your pet project, but it usually has no place in production application.